# What's the best way to put this

Tags: writing

> Facebook has made a difference in the English language: "Like" now could be an action verb besides(apart from) being a verb expressing a state of mind.

If you got what I'm trying to say, then is it the best way to put the sentence after the colon? It took me some effort for me at first to construct this sentence, and it looked strange to me in the beginning. Now it still does.

Comment: When wasn't *like* an action verb? Do you *like* this comment? :)

Comment: like was used to be only a verb expression state of mind. Let's assume what i said is true and then see what the best way to put it is.

Comment: @MaulikV *Like* is typically (but not exclusively) a stative verb.

Comment: "Like" has always been an action verb. All verbs are actions. I understand what you are trying to say but I don't agree. Facebook has not changed English; in normal conversation, Like still just means Like unless you qualify it. Only in the Facebook universe does "Like" have any of the additional weight or meaning that you are referring to, so unless you are sure that the person with whom you are conversing knows that they are in a conversation about Facebook activities, expect people to understand you to be simply meaning "Like" in the traditional way.

Comment: Now I am curious what kind of action verb usage of "like" Facebook popularized.

Comment: I'm now, like, puzzled...

Comment: @Nigel - Perhaps that's true, but, when a certain domain (such as the "Facebook universe") becomes big enough, there can a perceptable change in how the public at large uses a word. If Facebook stays around long enough, sooner or later, a dictionary is bound to add a new definition under its entry for _like_, perhaps with a qualifier like [_social media_]. Moreover, sometimes there is [value](http://allfacebook.com/facebook-likes-marketing_b71874) in defining what a word "means" – even in a particular "universe".

Comment: Facebook certainly has changed the way we use *like.* By referring to clicking on a screen, it now refers to a physical action. *Like* and *love, feel,* etc. have long been described as occupying a kind of fuzzy zone as states and/or *mental actions*, in grammars.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for writing advice, which is largely opinion based.

Comment: I think what you meant is that "like" usually expresses an emotion, not a "state of mind".

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Facebook has made a difference in the English language: "Like" now can
>   be an action verb as well as being a verb expressing a state of mind.

Comment: I have two questions:1) what if I remove the "being" in your answer? 2)Why do you use can instead of could?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit hasty in answering this question, because I am not going to be able justify my answers to your questions using grammatical terms, but here goes:
1) Without the "being" the sentence construction suggests that "Like" can be both types of verbs at the same time.
2) I used "can" instead of "could" because "could" is conditional and needs to be paired with something like "or". 

For example ""Like" now could be an action verb or it could be a verb expressing a state of mind."

However that removes the idea that a "verb expressing a state of mind " was the original meaning.

Comment: *Could* and *can* often cause confusion because they each have multiple meanings and one use of *could* is to convey the past tense meaning of *can* (no longer able). JoAnne's change is required to remove the potential ambiguity.